# Angular project fails to load when deployed to non-root path in IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I've created a fresh Angular project, and I built it with `ng build`. Then I copied it to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\`. I've added it using "Convert to Application" in IIS Manager.

[image]

I then browse it, using `http://localhost:81/MyProject/`, but all subsequent requests made by Angular fail because they lack the `/MyProject` at the root. For example, from the tooltip, it tries to load `inline.bundle.js` from `http://localhost:81/inline.bundle.js/` instead of `http://localhost:81/MyProject/inline.bundle.js/`

[image]

How can I make it take into account the root `MyProject`?

Comment: Try researching about the web.config file. If I'm not mistaking, you can use that to rewrite all requests to the path you wish. I had to do it to deploy to Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<base href>` property to point to your sub directory ("MyProject") in the new app's `index.html` (or default page).

**Example:**

```
<base href="/MyProject/">
```

**Or**, for a more directory-agnostic, relative path approach (provided by the OP)

```
<base href="./">
```

Comment: Thanks! This led me to the right direction, but I used `<base href="./">` instead, since that will work regardless of the name under which I deploy the site. There already was `<base href="/">`, I just needed to add a dot in front.